# Not able to recieve data after BIND_LISTENER deprecated

Tags: android, wear-os

my app has been working fine until BIND_LISTENER deprecated and I have done any change needed but my app is not working. I send the data from wear successfully but nothing happen on the phone side.

My main code on the wear (the sender):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private TextView mTextView;
GoogleApiClient googleClient;
String WEARABLE_DATA_PATH = "/wearable_data";
ArrayList<String> dataBlock = new ArrayList();
Button startButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    });


    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    // Build a new GoogleApiClient that includes the Wearable API
    googleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Wearable.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.v("CONNECTED", "CONNECTED");
    DataMap map = new DataMap();
    map.putLong("Time",System.currentTimeMillis());
    new SendToDataLayerThread(WEARABLE_DATA_PATH, map).start();
}

public void onStartClicked(View view) {
    Log.v("StartClicked", "in on start clicked");
    googleClient.connect();
}
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    Log.v("Suspended", "Suspended");

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.v("Failed", "onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
            + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
}


class SendToDataLayerThread extends Thread {
    String path;
    DataMap dataMap;


    // Constructor for sending data objects to the data layer
    SendToDataLayerThread(String p, DataMap data) {
        path = p;
        dataMap = data;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Construct a DataRequest and send over the data layer
        PutDataMapRequest putDMR = PutDataMapRequest.create(path);
        putDMR.getDataMap().putAll(dataMap);
        putDMR.setUrgent();
        PutDataRequest request = putDMR.asPutDataRequest();
        DataApi.DataItemResult result = Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(googleClient, request).await();
        if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            Log.v("myTag", "DataMap: " + dataMap + " sent successfully to data layer ");
        }
        else {
            // Log an error
            Log.v("myTag", "ERROR: failed to send DataMap to data layer");
        }
    }
}
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}
}
```

My wear Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myname.datacollector">
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

The listener  service  on the phone side:

```
public class ListenerService extends WearableListenerService {
//private static final String START_ACTIVITY_PATH = "/start-activity";
private static final String WEARABLE_DATA_PATH = "/wearable_data";

public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    Log.v("myTag", "Test");
}

public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
    DataMap dataMap;
    Log.v("myTag", "DataMap received from watch: ");
    for (DataEvent event : dataEvents) {

        // Check the data type
        if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
            // Check the data path
            String path = event.getDataItem().getUri().getPath();
            if (path.equals(WEARABLE_DATA_PATH)) {}
            dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(event.getDataItem()).getDataMap();
            Log.v("myTag", "DataMap received on watch: " + dataMap);
        }
    }
}
}
```

My phone manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.name.datacollector">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".ListenerService" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:scheme="wear"
                android:host="*"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me when I had to stop using the bind listener. The phone is not receiving anything because you have `android:exported="false"` in your phone's manifest. Either remove it or set it to `true` and you should be able to receive data again.

**EDIT:** You are also missing the path in the phone's manifest. You're using the path `/wearable_data` to send the message to the phone, but it will never receive it the path isn't listed in the manifest. Just add `android:pathPrefix="/wearable_data"` after `android:host="*"` in the `data` section of your `intent-filter`. You can read more about it [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/04/deprecation-of-bindlistener.html).

Comment: Just saw that you forgot to add the path to the phone's manifest. The edit above might help.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the comment, this did not make a difference for me. Anyway, I changed this way I'm sending the data and started from scratch following [this](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/117b05aad4db251f7534) and it is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

In order to send and sync data between the mobile and wear apps in your project **THEY MUST HAVE THE SAME PACKAGE NAME**, as stated in the Developer notes [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html),

> Packaging a Wear 1.x app with Android Studio
>
> To package a Wear 1.x app in Android Studio:
>
> 1. Ensure that both the watch and phone app modules have the same package name.

and here

> If your Wear 2.0 app has an accompanying phone app, use the same package name for your Wear app and that phone app.

Change the wear & mobile app to have the same package name:

```
com.example.myname.datacollector
```

or

```
com.example.name.datacollector
```

This stack overflow question will help you if you are unsure how to change an existing project module's package name [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)